# Define a \newif within a nested \ifdefined

Tags: conditionals

The MWE below attemps to define a `\newif` within a `\ifdefined`. This works fine, except when the file is loaded the second time.

As it is below generates the following error message:

> Incomplete \ifdefined; all text was ignored after line 1.

However if you comment out the `\newif` works as desired.

### Question:

How do I declare the `\newif` within the `\ifdefined`?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyHeader.tex}
    \ifdefined\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded\else
        \def\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded{}%
        \newcommand{\SomeCommand}{some command}%
        \newif\ifDTLnewdbonload%
    \fi
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\input{MyHeader.tex} \SomeCommand.

\input{MyHeader.tex} \SomeCommand.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\newif\csname ifDTLnewboload\endcsname`; but there are better ways.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order not to load a file twice, another method is preferable:

```
%%% MyHeader.tex
\ifdefined\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi

\gdef\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded{}
\newcommand{\SomeCommand}{some command}
\newif\ifDTLnewdbonload
```

If the file has already been loaded, the control sequence would be defined. So the conditional expands `\endinput` that stops reading the file. The `\expandafter` is just to finish the conditional. A different format would be

```
%%% MyHeader.tex
\ifdefined\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded\endinput\fi

\gdef\MyHeaderAlreadyIncluded{}
\newcommand{\SomeCommand}{some command}
\newif\ifDTLnewdbonload
```

because TeX always ends the line before `\endinput` does its work.

---

To answer the original question,

```
\expandafter\newif\csname ifDTLnewdbonload\endcsname
```

would work, because if TeX skips the `\else` branch, it will not "see" the already defined conditional.